# Controlling BLDC with IR 2130 - stuck at fault, unable to reset

Tags: arduino, mosfet, brushless-dc-motor, undervoltage

I'm working right now with the following circuit, trying to drive the BLDC motor with it.
[image: circuit]
I don't exactly know how it works (especially the overcurrent sensing part) and the man that designed it is currently unreachable so I can't simply ask him.

I'm trying to drive the BLDC motor with it and Arduino but the IR2130 is stuck at FAULT state (so it's not sending any output to the transistors) and I can't reset it in any way.
I've tried resetting it by setting all LINs in high state for 10us as the datasheet says but it won't work. I'm monitoring the FAULT state before the main controling loop begins and I still get 0 at it. There shouldn't be any currents flowing through the motor right then so why would it detect any overcurrent? I don't think undervoltage is the problem because I'm getting nice and stable 12V at Vcc

Comment: Check the voltage across R11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the /FAULT output is an open-drain output. You need an external pull-up resistor to your VCCIO logic supply voltage (3.3V or 5V).

The open-drain output has a low-on resistance in the 55-75 Ohm range. Any pull-up value comprised between 1k and 10k should do the job.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I simply changed FAULT in my Arduino program from INPUT to INPUT_PULLUP and now it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Current sensing is based on this formula :
R11 * Ampere used <= 0.5v .
Meaning R11 multiplied by "ampere used", must produce not more than 0.5v.
Anything above 0.5v considered "Fault condition". This R11 is selected as such a way that, it will limit the ampere intake. So selecting 0.01Ohms for R11 will allow(!!!) it to go upto 50A (!!!!). Heat produced by the R11 at 50A will be 50x50x0.01=25watt!!!

For example, you can use 2 unit of 0.33 5Watt ceramic resistor in parallel to get 0.165Ohms and you will get up to 3A limitations. Heat produced will be 3x3x0.165=1.44 watt.

Hope it helps.